# How can I make a dimension a multiple of another dimension?

Tags: android, android-resources, dimension

I was wondering if it is possible to make a dimension a multiple of another dimension in Android. E.g., so I can do something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="base">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="size_of_something">4*@dimen/base</dimen>
</resources>
```

Right now, I use a workaround like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="base_x1">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="base_x2">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="base_x3">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="base_x4">200dp</dimen>
    <!-- etc... -->
    <dimen name="size_of_something">@dimen/base_x4</dimen>
</resources>
```

But this means that I have to update all the multiples every time I change the base size, which is not only cumbersome, but also error-prone.

Comment: No, you can't. Use your workaround, it's perfect.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. Hopefully in the future Android will add this feature.

Comment: But, for the moment, we have to live with it... ;)

Comment: I submitted a feature request to Android: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65917&thanks=65917&ts=1392289972